# How do I start a desktop application from the browser on a Mac?

Tags: macos, browser

I'm building a web application that when finished will need to trigger a desktop app to open and load a specific file (or connect to a URL I'm passing to the desktop app).

I'm having a hard time finding documentation about how to do that on a Mac, can you point me to the right place?

Comment: Did you write the desktop application?

Answer (score 3):

You want to define a custom URL protocol.

Here is an example;

http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page

Here are some notes about how to do it on a Mac;

https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x
https://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/

Comment: Your link is helpful for Windows but as the author says "I do not have not a clue about similar technics for other operating systems such as Linus and Mac"